# How to set up cucumber with Main class and maven build

Tags: maven, kotlin, intellij-idea, junit, cucumber

I have made a project from where I intent to run integration tests using docker: https://github.com/navikt/bidrag-cucumber-nais

In this project, I have

- a kotlin application called `IntegrationTests.kt`
- a `pom.xml` which makes maven build the application

I would like to

- only run cucumber tests from the application: `IntegrationTests.kt`
- only run unit tests from maven

Issues I do not understand:

- from IntelliJ: when running junit tests, it will run cucumber and "regular" junit tests (this is expected behaviour)
- from IntelliJ: when running the application, `IntegrationTests.kt`, cucumber tests are run (this is expected behaviour)
- from maven: I have two profiles which eirher run junit-jupiter (by default) or junit-vintage (cucumber tests from cli). The profile running junit-vintage will not discover any tests... (?)
- from console: I cannot run the executable jar which are build... (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> from IntelliJ: when running junit tests, it will run cucumber and "regular" junit tests

IDEA has runners for both JUnit 4 and JUnit 5. They're enabled when you have either one on the class path.

> from maven: only junit tests with cucumber is run (junit vs junit-jupiter?)

Maven only enables one runner at a time, either JUnit 4 or JUnit 5 and defaults to the more modern version when multiple are present. You are using `cucumber-junit` which is a JUnit 4 integration. Consider adding `junit-vintage` in addition to `junit-jupiter`. That way JUnit 5 can run JUnit 4 tests or consider using [`junit-platform-engine`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine).

Comment: I do not buy this explanation... I am dependent on org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter which is a collection of all junit 5 (with junit 4 and vintage)

Comment: You have it the wrong way around. JUnit 5 = JUnit Platform + JUnit Jupiter + JUnit Vintage. https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview-what-is-junit-5

Comment: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter contains org.junit:junit-bom. This contains org.junit:junit and among others platforms/runners: org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher , org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner, and org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine. what am I missing?

Comment: You missed the difference between `dependencies` and `dependencyManagement`.

Comment: yes... junit 5 with maven accomplished using Surefire Plugin with Jupiter-engine

Comment: edited the question after your comments. thanks! I cannot get the vintage profile to work though...

Comment: Try making your project smaller with just a Junit4 and Junit5 test.

Comment: have you seen my project? it is bssically just a junit test (JUnit 5) and a cucumber test (junit 4 and main class)

Comment: it is a pop of what I am trying to achieve, Making an application in cucumber which is tested when building with junit 5. I have the junit 4 test just as a possibility to run the cucumber tests from the command lne

Comment: autocorrect.. grr... pop = poc (proof of concept)

Comment: I could look at your project and work out why it doesn't work. But that wouldn't help you.

Comment: true... I am not looking for why It do not work... I am looking for a solution to make it work

Comment: Rather you have to learn the process by which you methodically and structurally verify and correct your assumptions. This may require testing things that appear obvious just on the off chance they're not. For example you misunderstood the scope of JUnit Jupiter and never verified that it did indeed work that way.

Comment: that is also true... but when I am stuck and cannot see where the flaws of my direction are, this is hard... that is why I am hoping for a pointer of what might be wrong... like the information of me misunderstanding dependency and dependencyManagement...

Comment: So start by getting a minimal project to work and see where it fails as you add more components. There are also more people who know JUnit4/5 then Cucumber so more chance of getting help if that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226230/discussion-between-jactor-rises-and-m-p-korstanje).